# BOOST_DLL_ALIAS_SECTIONED missing specified BOOST_DLL_SECTION after performing a strip

Tags: boost, plugins

I created a shared library using BOOST using the following to specify the factory method:

```
BOOST_DLL_ALIAS_SECTIONED(
MyPlugin::create, // Plugin's factory method being exported
create_plugin,    // Alias for factory method.

MySectionName)  // The section name that all factory methods are grouped in.
```

The `create()` method returns a shared pointer to the MyPlugin object.

I then load the shared library and try to fetch the particular section using:

```
boost::dll::library_info inf(shared_library_path);
```

And then locate the above section with:

```
std::vector<std::string> sections = inf.sections();

if (std::find(sections.begin(), sections.end(), "MySectionName") == sections.end()) {
    // Do something
} else
{
    // Error out
}
```

If the shared library was *not* stripped, the above allows me to find
`MySectionName` within its contents and perform actions within the bracket.
If I however strip the shared library (default: strip library_name.so), the
above library info no longer lists the defined section and I hit the error out
condition.

I can protect the particular factory method during strip by specifying
"-K*create*" flag, but while that works with this simple shared library, more
complex libraries end up with more missing symbols and it almost feels
counterproductive to keep expanding the "-K" flag.

Is here an easier way of using BOOST for plugin creation using the above method
and still allow stripping out debug information without having to expand with
"-K" flag?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this with shorter section names:

- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/dll.hpp>
   #include <boost/dll/alias.hpp>

   namespace MyPlugin {
       struct X{};
       static auto create() {
           return std::make_shared<X>();
       }
   }

   BOOST_DLL_ALIAS_SECTIONED(
           MyPlugin::create, 
           Factory, 
           MySect)
  ```
- File `test1.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/dll.hpp>
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {
       boost::dll::library_info inf("libsotest.so");
       std::vector<std::string> s = inf.sections();

       auto found = (std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), "MySect") != s.end());
       std::cout << "Found: " << std::boolalpha << found << "\n";
   }
  ```

Prints:

[image]

In fact, I cannot compile it at all when the section name exceeds 9 characters:

```
test.cpp|11 col 1| error: static assertion failed: Some platforms require section names to be at most 8 bytes
||    11 | BOOST_DLL_ALIAS_SECTIONED(
```

Perhaps your problem is related to such restrictions?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the section name was less than 9 characters so my sample code was a tad misleading. I lowered the section name from what it was (7) to 5 for test purposes but I'm still not finding the defined section.

Lastly, the shared library sits on top of multiple levels of inheritance with some virtual and pure virtual functions sprinkled throughout, if that makes any difference.

Compiler is gcc 10.2.1 on Red Hat.

Comment: Can you make it a minimal self-contained example? [Here's](https://github.com/sehe/CentosDllPluginTest) my dockerized attempt which is easy to replicate using VsCode Remote devcontainer: https://imgur.com/a/EhuQtzo. Simple starter: `git clone https://github.com/sehe/CentosDllPluginTest && code CentosDllPluginTest/`